# The random function does not start correctly. If I click on the button the text doesn't change, but if I close and reopen the app it changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter, random

This script has the purpose of displaying the word "della gara" or "del match" in combination with "valida" or "valido, depending on the grammar rule if male or female. Don't worry, it works correctly :) Don't worry, even if the text is in a non-English language, it doesn't matter, because it prints quietly. All that is needed is to apply the random function with `sinonimo_partita_random` inside the for loop.

**PROBLEM**: The problem is that the random function doesn't start correctly when I click the Print button. Try clicking on the Print button many times, nothing happens.

I would like to display `sinonimo_partita_random`, but if I click it is always printed "della gara" or always "del match". While, if I close and reopen the script, the word is changed.

How can I make the random function fully functional when I click the Print button?

```
import random
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")
                      
sinonimi_partita_diz = {

        "della gara": {"genere" : "femminile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        "del match": {"genere" : "maschile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        }

valido_a_diz = {
    
            "valido" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "no"
            },        

            "valida" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "no"
            },                
        }

####################

text = tk.Text(root,width=43,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)

#THE PROBLEM IS HERE:
sinonimo_partita = ("della gara", "del match")
sinonimo_partita_random = random.choice(sinonimo_partita)

valido_a = ""
for key, value in valido_a_diz.items():
    if sinonimi_partita_diz[sinonimo_partita_random] == value:
        valido_a = key
        break

def print():
    text.delete(1.0,END)
    phrase = f"{sinonimo_partita_random} {valido_a}"
    text.insert(tk.END, phrase)

button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = print)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)
```

Comment: @as_99. Remove either the button2.pack or the button2.place. You don't need both.

Comment: Also you are missing root.mainloop().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the order of your code, so the `random` function is now inside the `print()` function and at the end `root.mainloop()` was missing.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def print():
    sinonimo_partita_random = random.choice(sinonimo_partita)
    valido_a = ""
    for key, value in valido_a_diz.items():
        if sinonimi_partita_diz[sinonimo_partita_random] == value:
            valido_a = key
            break
    text.delete(1.0,END)
    phrase = f"{sinonimo_partita_random} {valido_a}"
    text.insert(tk.END, phrase)
                      
sinonimi_partita_diz = {

        "della gara": {"genere" : "femminile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        "del match": {"genere" : "maschile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        }

valido_a_diz = {
    
            "valido" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "no"
            },        

            "valida" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "no"
            },                
        }

sinonimo_partita = ["della gara", "del match"]

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")

text = tk.Text(root,width=43,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)

button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = print)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I would like the loop to stay outside the print function. You have changed the order of the code too much. I would like the code to be structured in a very similar way to my code: as much as possible to mine

Comment: ok, but in your code the only loop you have is the mainloop() and that's the reason you always have the same output.. mainloop only processes events, it doesn't call your functions multiple times. So```random.choice(sinonimo_partita)``` is just called once.

Comment: @Jas_99 Your requirement *"I would like the loop to stay outside the print function"* is the cause of your issue.